# Can we set custom image for scrollbar of UITableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to set my custom image for `UITableView` scrollbar.

For that i found this link: [WKVerticalScrollBar for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wkverticalscrollbar)

But it seems too complex to implement. It is just an image for `TableView` scrollbar.

Is there any other easy way to do that?

**UPDATE - 1**

My Tableview has only these 2 subviews

```
"<UIImageView: 0x6c2c9f0; frame = (0 778; 360 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c2ca60>>",
"<UIImageView: 0x6c06680; frame = (353 778; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c2be70>>"
```

With that i Have tried with both index but any of it not working

```
    tblvw.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    NSLog(@"tblview subview : %@",tblvw.subviews);
    UIImageView *imgview = [tblvw.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slider-strip.png"];
```

After making `tblvw.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;` 
I came to know that i was not getting the 2nd imageview as subview & only 1st imageview. So i tried using `[tblvw.subviews objectAtIndex:1];` but also not working

Comment: Yes you can set custom image. I have seen many game apps that using custom images on UITableView ScrollBar but I don't have any logic how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Perfectly:

**EDIT** : Note: Best implementation is to have  **Vertical Image**. For example like............................................. [image]

```
 if([self.tableView.subviews count] > 2){
 UIImageView *scrollViewBarImgView = [self.tableView.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
 UIImage *imgBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; //your image here
 [scrollViewBarImgView setImage:imgBar];
 }
 else{

   UIImageView *scrollViewBarImgView = [self.tableView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
   UIImage *imgBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; //your image here
   [scrollViewBarImgView setImage:imgBar];
 }
```

Comment: Please note that while it may work here and now, this may break *any* time in the future.

Comment: Try with index 1 : UIImageView *scrollViewBarImgView = [self.tableView.subviews objectAtIndex:1]; //with index 1
 UIImage *imgBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; //your image here
 [scrollViewBarImgView setImage:imgBar];